# magento 2 override file Adapter.php

Tags: magento2

I have to **override** the following file

vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/Adapter.php

but it's not working after writing the preference in **etc/di.xml**. If anyone knows please help.
Below is the code I am using:
Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter" />
```

Vendor/Module/Model/Adapter.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandPoolInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\ValueHandlerPoolInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Data\PaymentDataObjectFactory;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Validator\ValidatorPoolInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


class Adapter extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter
{
    /**
     * @var ValueHandlerPoolInterface
     */
    private $valueHandlerPool;

    /**
     * @var ValidatorPoolInterface
     */
    private $validatorPool;

    /**
     * @var CommandPoolInterface
     */
    private $commandPool;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $storeId;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $formBlockType;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $infoBlockType;

    /**
     * @var InfoInterface
     */
    private $infoInstance;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $eventManager;

    /**
     * @var PaymentDataObjectFactory
     */
    private $paymentDataObjectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerInterface
     */
    private $commandExecutor;

    /**
     * Logger for exception details
     *
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(ManagerInterface $eventManager, ValueHandlerPoolInterface $valueHandlerPool, PaymentDataObjectFactory $paymentDataObjectFactory, $code, $formBlockType, $infoBlockType, CommandPoolInterface $commandPool = null, ValidatorPoolInterface $validatorPool = null, CommandManagerInterface $commandExecutor = null, LoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($eventManager, $valueHandlerPool, $paymentDataObjectFactory, $code, $formBlockType, $infoBlockType, $commandPool, $validatorPool, $commandExecutor, $logger);
    }

    public function isAvailable(CartInterface $quote = null){
        parent::isAvailable();
        die("fsdfsdfsdf");
        }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function cancel(InfoInterface $payment)
    {
        die("core test");
        //$this->executeCommand('cancel', ['payment' => $payment]);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override Adapter.php file using preference.

1. Add preference code line in di.xml as per example
2. Upload Adapter.php file in your module

   Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Model

**Note**: Please update namespace in Adapter.php file

Please check preference example. It will help you.

https://github.com/csvikram44/Preference-Example

Comment: If it help you then please mark it correct. Thanks

Comment: Its a perfect Way if You Want to Override Whole class Or Private Methods.

Comment: @VikramKumar I've followed the same as per the github url but its not working, its calling the core file only.

Comment: @Rahulpandey Yes, I just override file. You need customize code. What you want to do?

Comment: @VikramKumar I've to customize cancel method, I've to call void in cancel method. like this  public function cancel(InfoInterface $payment)
    {
       $this->void($payment);
    }

Comment: @VikramKumar any idea on it?

Comment: @Rahulpandey It will not for cancel the order. Please describe what is your requirement? So I will help you.

Comment: @VikramKumar I've to call void on click on cancel button in admin orders so for that i have made changes in same core file Adapter.php, it was working fine for me so just need to override cancel method of it.

Comment: @Rahulpandey AS per mine you are editing wrong file. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Please override getCancelUrl() method from file vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View.php line 349. You can do this using plugin also.

public function getCancelUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('sales/*/cancel');
    }

Comment: If it help you than please tick mark right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

Create File:-

> path:- Vendor\Module\Model\Method\Adapter.php

```
    <?php
    
    
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Method;
    
    
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandPoolInterface;
    use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\ValueHandlerPoolInterface;
    use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Data\PaymentDataObjectFactory;
    use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Validator\ValidatorPoolInterface;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    
    class Adapter extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter
    {
        public function __construct(ManagerInterface $eventManager, ValueHandlerPoolInterface $valueHandlerPool, PaymentDataObjectFactory $paymentDataObjectFactory, $code, $formBlockType, $infoBlockType, CommandPoolInterface $commandPool = null, ValidatorPoolInterface $validatorPool = null, CommandManagerInterface $commandExecutor = null, LoggerInterface $logger = null)
        {
            parent::__construct($eventManager, $valueHandlerPool, $paymentDataObjectFactory, $code, $formBlockType, $infoBlockType, $commandPool, $validatorPool, $commandExecutor, $logger);
        }
    
        public function isAvailable(CartInterface $quote = null){
            parent::isAvailable();
            <!-- your code -->
        }
    }
```

Create di.xml

> path:- Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Method\Adapter" />
</config>
```

Comment: I've followed the same as per the github url but its not working, its calling the core file only

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Himanshu I've updated the code in question. Please check

Comment: I have to override the cancel method.